# Socket.io like PHP Implementation

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, ionic-framework, server

I am working on a little personal project on Ionic2 framework, and one part of my application requires a chat to be implemented. So I went and read about Socket.IO and it's implementations and it is really awesome. But the drawback for my project is that the frontend will not be able to host NodeJS, so I had to quit the idea of using Socket.io. 
is there any alternative/Solution to make the PHPserver maintain a bidirectional connection for the chat? My guessing was to use GET/POST between the Ionic App and the server but that will be heavy on both client and server since it has to check on every short amount of time (less than a second to give the real-time like behavior).

Thank you.

Comment: Ratchet: http://socketo.me/

Comment: Thank you @JeremyHarris but is it possible to provide and handle multiple clients @ the same time?  And does it have any limitations I should know of before starting ?

Comment: You can read the manual or watch a tutorial on it. I'm just providing a possible suggestion.